# aws cognito:how to put a condition on the group of user before login?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

I want to put a condition before login which should check if the user logging is part of group manager or not. It not then login should be denied. I am able to retrieve group of the user but I am unable to put a condition on the same.
Any help would be appreciated
here is a snippet of the code:

```
const Login= () => {
  const [Username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const onSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    Auth.currentSession().then(res=>{
        var cognitoGroups = res.accessToken.payload["cognito:groups"]
        console.log(`group: ${cognitoGroups}`)
    });

    const user = new CognitoUser({
      Username: Username,
      Pool: UserPool
    });
    const authDetails = new AuthenticationDetails({
      Username: Username,
      Password: password,
      cognitoGroups: "Manager"
    });

    user.authenticateUser(authDetails, {
      onSuccess: data => {
        console.log("onSuccess:", data);
      },

      onFailure: err => {
        console.error("onFailure:", err);
      }

    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It is possible.

AWS Cognito has many triggers (lambda functions). Write validation check on lambda function and set that lambda as the trigger (Pre Authentication Lambda Trigger). For above use case please read this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-authentication.html)